# Android OpenGL: draw to half-sized screen resolution

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to figure out a way to draw to a half-sized screen resolution and then scaling x2 and drawing. This is to speed up rendering to get a better frames per second. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SurfaceHolder.setFixedSize(int width, int height)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize%28int,%20int%29).

A call to this method will make your application fill the number of pixels you put in as arguments and then it will scale it up on the screen. This basically means you are filling fewer pixels but it will still render on the whole screen.

Comment: Thanks! That works. It blurs a little though-- any ideas on how to prevent that?

Comment: @coda: That's the way it works. If it's too blurry, you have to increase the *width* and *height* value.

Comment: No way to turn off antialiasing? Just do a nearest neighbor kind of coloration?

Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any ways to achieve that.